# filter SqlAlchemy column value by number of resulting characters

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How can I filter SqlAlchemy column by number of resulting Characters,

Here is a kind of implementation I am looking at,

query = query.filter(Take_Last_7_Characters(column_1) == '0321334')

Where "Take_Last_7_Characters" fetches the last 7 characters from the resulting value of column_1

So How can I implement Take_Last_7_Characters(column_1) ??

Answer (score 1):

use `sqlalchemy.sql.expression.func` , to generate SQL functions.

[check for more info](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/core/expression_api.html)

Comment: Got it ,

query = query.filter(func.substr(QueryLine.column_1, 1, 7) == '0321334')

But now , the value '0321334' varies , it can be different with different length

Something like , '00000001234567','00000000123123','4321'

With the above values How can I make sure I select the last 7 characters only ?

Comment: try it in sql first, then can convert to SqlAlchemy.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the `func` to generate SQL functions as directed by @tuxuday.
Note that the code is RDBMS-dependant. The code below runs for `SQLite`, which offers `SUBSTR` and `LENGTH` functions. Your actual database might have different names for those (`LEN, SUSBSTRING, LEFT, RIGHT`, etc).

```
qry = session.query(Test)
qry = qry.filter(func.SUBST(Test.column_1, func.LENGTH(Test.column_1) - 6, 7) == '0321334')
```